# Sharing common data in C for scientific computing

Tags: c, design-patterns, dry, scientific-computing

In assignments where I have been forced to use C for scientific computing (rather than say, C++, my default choice), I often come across the following pattern:

There's usually a set of data that is commonly needed by many functions. For example, in solving differential equations, I would need to know number of points, the equations' parameters, etc:

```
struct parameters{
    unsigned int num_x;
    double length_x;
    // so forth
};
```

I often end up having to combine them in a structure and then end up repeating myself in nearly every function: `void f(struct parameters* p, ...)`. This wouldn't be so bad if it made sense for every function to have it as part of its interface, but it is not always the case, and I dislike the repetition anyway.

Furthermore, it is not always meaningful to have all these parameters in one structure, but splitting it up would make the interface more unmanageable.

Are there any workarounds or useful design patterns to deal with this? Making a global `p` would fix this, but justifying the use of a global when they are generally not recommended is difficult.

Comment: If all these parameters are effectively constants, there's nothing too wrong with making them global.

Comment: Flatly rejecting the use of globals on "religious" grounds is as bad as plastering globals all over the place. If globals actually solve the problem, use them. The primary consideration should be to use your brain.

Comment: Technically, if a function accesses/modifies data that originates outside itself, that data is logically part of the function's interface - so, for understanding by mere mortals, it is better to make that explicit.     That is equally true whether the data is passed via an argument, or is a global.  Practically, passing it as an argument is usually preferred.    In any event, if you don't want to pass data as an argument and don't want to pass it as a global, there aren't many options in standard C, other than saving to an external file.

Comment: @n.m. They are set by the user so read from stdin

Answer (score 5):

To my mind, there are two big reasons not to use global variables:

1. Since they're accessible everywhere, it can be impossible to keep track of when and how they get changed.
2. Their use makes it much more difficult to turn some standalone code into a utility function (a library, for example) that can be easily called from another program, with perhaps multiple instances.

But sometimes, there is data that is just truly global, potentially needed in all parts of a program, and if that's the case, I don't believe there should be any stigma against making it global, if it basically *is*.

You can dutifully pass around a pointer to your "shared" or "common" data (as you suggested), and often this is absolutely the right pattern, but in that case you've basically reintroduced problem #1.

And if you're sure you're never going to want to repackage your program as a separable, callable library, objection #2 goes away, too.

As Mark Benningfield suggested in a comment, the reason not to use globals is not just because everyone says you shouldn't.  If you know what you're doing, and if a global isn't going to cause you problems, you should go ahead and use it.

Me, the only thing I insist on is that if a variable is global, it must have a nice, long, descriptive name.  One- or two-character global variable names are right out.

(But with all of that said, you will usually find that global variables, like `goto`s, can be kept to a bare minimum.  The general advice to steer clear of them when possible, though that advice is indeed sometimes overzealously or religiously applied, is usually right.)

Answer (score 1):

As generally you will be just passing a pointer around, using one big struct may be prefererd. You can document in your functions which members it uses (its actual interface).

You could break down the struct in a number of structs for different types of computation, all having distinct members, and can combine them all in the big struct.

There may be no preferred design pattern.

Answer (score 0):

One method I have used in the past is to declare a set of macro constants at the file level - your example would then be something akin to

```
#define NUM_X <value>
#define LENGTH_X <value>
```

These are of course substituted by the preprocessor, which in a global-averse situation is beneficial.

Comment: I should have probably said these are not constants but read from the user. I generally don’t like using macros anyway unless absolutely necessary.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to avoid using global variables but only want to set your structure once, then you can write a module to do just that.

parameters.h:

```
struct t_param{
   unsigned int num_x;
   double length_x;
   // so forth
}; 

int get_parameters(struct t_param * out);
int init_parameters(const struct t_param* in);
```

parameters.c:

```
#include <string.h>
#include "parameters.h"
static struct t_param parameters = {0,0.0};

static int initialized = 0;

int init_paramaters(const t_param* in)
{     
   if(initialized == 0)
   {
      memcpy(&parameters, in);
      initialized = 1;
      return 0;
   }else
   {
      return -1;
   }  
}  

int get_parameters(t_param *out)
{
   if(initialized == 0)
   {
      return -1;
   }else
   {
      memcpy(out, &parameters);
      return 0;
   }  
}
```

**Edit: Traded out member assignment for `memcpy` calls.**

Comment: Erm aren’t you still using globals?

Comment: No, because the structure is housed in the module.  No other module has direct access to it -- they must use the functions to either initialize it or get it.  Any time you need the runtime constants, you would use variables instead of a `struct`.  You could also rewrite this to pass a `struct` in and out, in which case `t_param` would need to be global, but you would create an instance for each module that needs it.

Comment: I modified the answer to pass structs rather than variables.